# Correct way of overriding CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working with Bootstrap and for my site I want to override certain default settings it comes with. A lot of Bootstrap rules are quite deeply nested and thus most often than not take priority over whatever I might define.

In my overrides css file, do I have a better option than to slap

```
!important
```

on each rule, or is that how everybody's handling it these days?

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, this works for me.

- If you aren't already using LESS, take some time to figure it out, it will save you heaps of 
  time and makes it easy to keep everything organised http://lesscss.org. You will be well rewarded ;)
- Instead of editing the original Bootstrap LESS files and losing everything on the next Bootstrap update, create a new theme-css.less file and perhaps a theme.variables.less file and save them in the same directory as your Bootstrap LESS files
- Edit bootstrap.less so that your new files are compiled correctly,

  ..

  // CSS Reset
  @import "reset.less";
  // Core variables and mixins

  @import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
  @import "mixins.less";

  @import "theme-variables.less"; // <==== Your custom CSS variables

  // Grid system and page structure
  @import "scaffolding.less";
  @import "grid.less";
  @import "layouts.less";

  // Base CSS
  @import "type.less";
  @import "code.less";
  @import "forms.less";
  @import "tables.less";

  @import "theme-css.less"; // <==== Your custom CSS

  ..
- Use the [Bootstrap customise page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables) to located the names of the variables that govern much of the the CSS which you may wish to customise. Change these as req'd and add to your theme.variables.less file
- Use the LESS nested rules as per http://lesscss.org/  . <== this is important. It hugely simplifies what would otherwise be complex CSS

If you are new to LESS I realise that this isn't a simple 5 minute fix, but once you get it setup and start using the nested rules your CSS will be beautifully simple and easy to maintain.

**UPDATE Jun 2015**
The above technique is a bit dated now. Still works but [Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315105/jake)  suggested a change which I like and it simplifies long-term maintenance.

Instead of editing the main bootstrap.less file:

- create a new theme.less file
- import bootrap.less and your custom changes, e.g.:

  @import "path-to/bootstrap.less;
  @import "path-to/custom.less;
- compile theme.less

Doing it this way means there's less chance that your custom changes could be lost if you update your bootstrap.less file

Comment: Just a thought: Instead of adding the import of your custom theme css into the bootstrap.less, it would be better to create a main theme css and import bootstrap into it, then modify bootstrap settings AFTER the import. With your method above, the import of theme-css would be lost when bootstrap was updated.

Comment: @Jake if you have a setup where your bootstrap less files could be overwritten then you could certainely fine-tune this. What I've done recently is save a copy this bootstrap.less file outside the bootstrap less directory, adjust the paths to the bootstrap less files (e.g. [at]import "bootstap/less/reset.less";), and compile the copy.  Whatever works best for you. You'll probably find that you want to import your custom.less file at the position I suggested, not at the very end. Importing partway means your custom settings will take effect before the BS components (nav, buttons etc) are built.

Comment: Importing the bootstrap.less into a custom less file, then editing bootstrap variables AFTER the import compiles with your changed variables and avoids editing bootstrap files. Give this a shot: `@import "bootstrap.less"; @brand-primary: red;`

Comment: Hey @Jake, your suggestion works for me as well :) I updated my answer above. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Cheers @David Taiaroa.  Thanks for the nod :)

Answer (score 4):

`!important` is a last resort, and should ideally never be used. if you want to override CSS, then honor CSS cascading rules: more "specific" rules always win out over less "specific" rules. e.g.

```
<div id="someid">Howdy</div>


div { 
    color: red;
}

div#someid {
    color: blue;
}
```

makes the text blue, even though both are pointing at the same element, because the #someid makes the second rule more specific.

Comment: I understand the specificity rules, but using IDs doesn't seem like a solution that would scale long term. For example when applying css rules to procedurally generated parts of the page (e.g. populate a table worth of <td>s from a backend). That's why I have to end up using !important, and I'm wondering if  can do better.

Comment: if you're generating html, you can always generate inline styles, which will always be "most specific". e.g. `<td style="color: red">` will override `td { color: blue; }`. except, of course, if you've littered your css with !important, in which case all bets are off.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the CSS scoring works for selectors.

Inline style trump everything in the CSS.
eg. `<p style="margin:0;">` will override everything in your CSS file.

ID count as 1000 points: #sub-head, #page-wrapper
Class count as 100 pointsZ: .sub-head, .page-wrapper
Elements count as 10 points: a, p, div, ul, li
Pseudo Selectors count as 1: :hover, :first-child, :last-child

Which ever selector has the highest about of points for the style will get rendered on the page.

!important is another trump card to pull and should only be used rarely.
For instance I like to use it for coloring special text or margins.

Here is a good link that explains it more in detail.
Its very simple.

[Link](http://www.agileapproach.com/blog-entry/css-specificity-scoring)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way based on ***the order*** of linked css files in the head of html document. Great explanation is here: https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

---

**Funny part of that**

I was using !important as well and when writing it I was always thinking what kind of weird way is that :D

Answer (score 0):

my answer to this. I add a custom style sheet AFTER the bootstrap style sheet then every thing works.

(wordpress site with custom bootstrap theme) - in this case, problem fixed after I enqueue my style sheet after bootstrap style sheet

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and first thing you should do is check the order of your stylesheet links in the head of your html file.

Link to the bootstrap CSS first, then, on the following line, link to your style.css (or similar) file.

If you have this order reversed, you may have trouble overriding certain style elements.